# Почему строка "Введите букву" выводится 2 раза?

Tags: java, циклы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        char ch;
        do {
            System.out.println("Введите букву");
            ch = (char) System.in.read();
        } while (ch != 'q');
    }
}
```

Comment: Вторая (невидимая) буква - конец строки.

Comment: Можно по подробнее пожалуйста прохождение цикла расписать, почему у нас \n бесконечно не гоняется циклом , а исчезает после 2 выполнения?

Comment: @stepanevgen2013 Функция `read()` может читать только один байт из консоли, если вы вводите символы состоящие из нескольких байт, то цикл начинает крутиться до тех пор пока не считается все, после этого вернёт -1, после чего чтение заблокирует поток, пока не будут новые байты. Потом все повторится. Сразу можно заметить, что можно использовать уложенные циклы, чтобы разделить ввод и вывод.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Я использовал режим отладки (дебага), чтобы в этом разораться.
Оказывается, когда вы вводите символ (например 'k') и нажимаете клавишу Enter, через поток `System.in` вводится 2 символа!

Первый - тот который вы ввели (например 'k'), а второй - невидимый символ перевода строки ('\n') из-за клавиши `Enter`. Соответственно мы 2 раза проходимся по циклу (так как в input потоке считались 2 символа).

И совершенно не имеет значения использовать ли цикл с постусловием `do-while` или с предусловием `while`.